# Scrollviewer ActualHeight exceeds the screen resolution

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scrollviewer, actualheight

I have a `Grid` with these rows settings:
(I can't post much code, sorry)

```
RowDefinition Height="1*"

RowDefinition Height="120"
```

Inside that grid I have a `ScrollViewer` with `Height="Auto"` and `verticalAlignment = "Stretch"` at Row 0.

At row 2 I have another grid with a fix height of 60 pixels.

When I do `this.UpdateLayout` (inside an `UserControl`), then the `scrollviewer.ActualHeight` goes to 2332, which is the same size of an image inside it and exceed the resolution screen. Why its not updating to fit the screen?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the grid itself inside of?

Comment: Setting the first RowDefinition Height to "Star" - doesn't make much sense as it'll never fill the remaining space, "Star" is normally used for the very last row or the very last column. Normally, UpdtaeLayout isn't needed - after all it work asynchronously so you watch window won't display the right figures anyway.

Comment: the grid has a scrollviewer, a grid and other stuff that doesnt matter. Ive already tried putting 0.8* and 0.2* or anything similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place the outer `Grid` in f.i. a `StackPanel` with orientation vertical, then there might not be a limit on the height of the grid, and then not a vertical limit on the `ScrollViewer`. Place the `Grid` in a `DockPanel`, or set a (maximum) height of the `Grid`. Then the `ScrollViewer` will have a limited height.

Comment: this kind didnt solve. But made me notice the mistake. My main container of the userControl was a stackpanel. When I changed it to Grid. It worked! :D ty

Answer (score 0):

Used MinHeight,MaxHeight

```
<ScrollViewer 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Grid.Column ="0"    
            MinHeight="60"
            MaxHeight="190"
            Grid.Row="0"
            />
```

then adjust your Scrollviewer on  screen resolution